Homology class of an analytic subvariety in a compact complex manifold
For an analytic subvariety represents a nontrivial homology class, is it possible to be a torsion class? I guess that the integral homology class of any analytic cycles can not be a torsion class because they can be normalized as a complex manifold and immerse into M, in this sense they are sort of orientable. I tried to prove it by Poincare duality. My idea is to intersect it transversely with another analytic subvariety, if such variety exists, then the topological intersection number must be positive. For projective variety it is true. How about a general compact manifold?
I am not sure my guess is true or not,and if it is true, how to prove?

You should add more detail, starting with: Are you working with homology any cycles in a compact complex manifold? Kahler manifold? Projective variety?.....

@Kohan: in a compact complex manifold

Then edit your question accordingly.

Keep in mind that a compact complex submanifold in a compact complex manifold can be homologically trivial.

@Kohan: I am curious that if it is nontrivial, could it be a torsion class?

But in a Kahler manifold each analytic cycle defines a nontrivial element of real homology, in particular, it cannot be torsion.

@Kohan：could you explain why in Kahler manifold each analytic cycle defines a nontrivial element?

You integrate a suitable power of the Kahler form over the cycle. The integral is necessarily positive. Hence, the cycle is nontrivial over $\mathbb R$. It should be in Ballmann's book on Kahler manifolds.

Here is a simple example. Take $X$ which is a secondary Hopf surface, $\mathbb R P^3\times S^1$. It is the quotient of $\mathbb C^2\setminus \{0\}$ by a complex-linear action of $\Gamma={\mathbb Z}\times {\mathbb Z}_2$ where the first factor acts as the group of dilations by powers of $2$ and generator of the second factor acts as $-Id$. The group $\Gamma$ preserves ${\mathbb C}^*\subset C^2\setminus \{0\}$ and the projection of ${\mathbb C}^*$ to $X$ is a smooth analytic cycle $C$ (an elliptic complex curve). One verifies (using for instance the Kunneth formula) that $[C]\ne 0$ in $H_2(X)$ but $[2C]=0$.
There are much more interesting examples of compact complex  3-dimensional manifolds: Taubes proved (Annals of Math, 1993) that for every oriented smooth compact 4-manifold $M$, the connected sum of $M$ with some number of copies of $\mathbb C P^2$, with the opposite orientation, is half-conformally-flat. Taking the twistor bundle over such connected sums results in a compact complex 3-dimensional manifolds with very complicated topology. By looking at such manifolds, you can probably find even more pathological examples of analytic cycles.

Thanks for your brilliant examples.
